# Can anyone tell me why axios content-type is undefined on this response

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have an array of image url that is coming from frontend that I need to save on my DB. I would like to verify that they are actually images before saving them on my DB. I read that I can use axios to make a request to the url.
So, I wrote something like this:

```
await Promise.all(imageURL?.map( async(item, index) =\>{
                  const stringURL = item?.split('//');
                  const stringURLs = stringURL\[1\]?.split('/');
                  if(item?.startsWith('https') ){
                  console.log(stringURL, 'this is string url');
                  try {
                  const image = await axios.get(item, {
                  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                     });
                        console.log(image.headers, image.headers\['Content-Type'\], 'see')
                   if(image.headers\['Content-Type'\] === 'image/png' || image.headers\['Content-Type'\] === 'image/jpg' || image.headers\['Content-Type'\] === 'image/jpeg' && image?.headers?.Server === 'Cloudinary'){
                  validatedImgURLArray?.push(item)
                        };

              } catch (error) {
                return console.log('error has occured during image url validation');
              }
              }
             
             
          }))
      }
```

When I `console.log(image.headers)`, it showed objects which included 'Content-Type'. I was wondering if I could use the content type to determine if the response is an image or not before saving it to my DB. Unfortunately, I cant access the content-type as it returns undefine.

Comment: Seems like a thing to ask the person running that server?

Comment: It is actually coming from cloudinary. Do you mean that cloudinary made it impossible to access the headers? Is there any other way I could check if the response file is an image aside using the headers?

Comment: Can you please show the actual output of `console.log(image.headers)`?